# Helm how to define .Release.Name value

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have created basic helm template using `helm create` command. While checking the  template for Ingress its adding the string RELEASE-NAME and appname like this `RELEASE-NAME-microapp`

How can I change `.Release.Name` value?

```
helm template --kube-version 1.11.1  microapp/

# Source: microapp/templates/ingress.yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: RELEASE-NAME-microapp
  labels:
    app: microapp
    chart: microapp-0.1.0
    release: RELEASE-NAME
    heritage: Tiller
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

This depends on what version of Helm you have; `helm version` can tell you this.

In Helm version 2, it's the value of the `helm install --name` parameter, or absent this, a name Helm chooses itself.  If you're checking what might be generated via `helm template` that also takes a `--name` parameter.

In Helm version 3, it's the first parameter to the `helm install` command.  Helm won't generate a name automatically unless you explicitly ask it to `helm install --generate-name`.  `helm template` also takes the same options.

Also, in helm 3, if you want to specify a name explicitly, you should use the `--name-template` flag. e.g. `helm template --name-template=dummy` in order to use the name `dummy` instead of `RELEASE-NAME`

Comment: Worth mentioning that in helm 3 it no longer autogenerates name for you and you should instead use --generate-name flag if you want a randomly generated name.

Comment: Also, in helm 3, if you want to specify a name explicitly, you should use the `--name-template` flag. e.g. `helm template --name-template=dummy` in order to use the name `dummy` instead of `RELEASE-NAME`

Comment: I've updated this answer to take these into account, thanks!

Answer (score 9):

As of helm 3.9 the flag is --release-name, making the command: `helm template --release-name <release name>`