# where to override .Release.Name in helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I created a helm chart which is deriving value of `app.kubernetes.io/instance` from a template value like this:

```
labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "mychart.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "mychart.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
```

I don't know in which file and how to override its value. I don't want to override it by command line as described at [Helm how to define .Release.Name value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718202/helm-how-to-define-release-name-value)

Comment: Why is it that you would like to set the .Release.Name in the chart? I am thinking there may be other ways to address your concern.

Comment: The idea is to treat delivered package as installer for deployer (with no configuration provided) and still be able to control the names of services, deployemnts etc. Anyways, I might be just speculating too much as part of my learning.

Comment: You could control the names of the services and deployments etc. by setting fixed names in those resources or a name from the values.yaml. See https://docs.helm.sh/chart_best_practices/#resource-naming-in-templates

Answer (score 8):

The intention is that you don't set the `.Release.Name` within the helm chart. It is either set to an automatically generated value by helm when the user runs `helm install` or is set by the user as a parameter with `helm install <name>`. Imagine if the chart were to set the value of `.Release.Name` - the user would still be able to set a different value for it with `helm install <name>` and there would then be a conflict where it wouldn't be clear which name would be used.